# Weasyprint 'cairo' error on Windows 10 x64

Tags: python, django, cairo, weasyprint

I want to use WeasyPrint to render html to pdf in django.

I followed all the steps in the WeasyPrint documentation. But I'm getting this error again.

```
cannot load library 'C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1
cannot load library 'libcairo.so': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1
```

I also set the system variables properly. I check the location of the files with the `WHERE` command. The `PATH` variable outputs the address I have defined. But I keep getting this error.

**Where's my fault?**

Comment: Sorry I forgot, the python version I used was 3.8, the django version 3.0